# How to trigger button in one view and animate other object in another view in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, core-data

While creating animation logic so that when the button is pressed, the Card would swipe away, however, with the current approach by using State and Binding nothing happens.
I suppose the trick here is that I'm not letting the card view know when the button is triggered.
Here's button where `@State private var isFLipped = false` :

```
Button(action: {
                // Handle button action
              //  isTapped.toggle()
                isFLipped.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("")
                    .frame(width: 70, height: 50)
                    .background(Color("Easy"))
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
            }
```

Here's SingleCardView:

```
ZStack {
         RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
             .fill(Color.white)
             
             
             .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).stroke(getColor(), lineWidth: 2))// Here we change the border color based on the swipe direction
             .shadow(radius: 3)

         VStack {
             NavigationStack {
                         
                 Text(card.term ?? "Unnamed Card")
                 Divider()
                                     if isTapped {
                                         Text(card.definition ?? "Unnamed Card")
                                     }
                        }

         }
     }
     .frame(width: 300, height: 500)
     
     .rotation3DEffect(
                             Angle(degrees: isFLipped ? 360: 0),
                             axis: (x: 0, y: isFLipped ? 360 : 0, z: 0)
                             
                 )

     .onTapGesture {
         isTapped.toggle()
     }

 }
```

Comment: Can you provide a more minimal example of the issue without irrelevant code? This makes it easier to comprehend.

Comment: Thanx, I have provided new example

Comment: This is not a [mre]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SwiftUI way/most efficient of doing this would be to have a value type in an `@State` and sharing `isFlipped` as an `@Binding`

```
import SwiftUI

struct SampleSharedManagerView: View {
    @State private var isFlipped: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack{
            List {
                Section("first") {
                    FirstView(isFlipped: $isFlipped)
                }
                Section("second") {
                    SecondView(isFlipped: $isFlipped)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @Binding var isFlipped: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "person")
            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: isFlipped ? 360: 0), axis: (x: 0, y: isFlipped ? 360 : 0, z: 0))
        
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: isFlipped)
    }
}
struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var isFlipped: Bool
    var body: some View {
        Button("Toggle") {
            isFlipped.toggle()
        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        
    }
}
```

But if we assume that the 2 Views are separated by various layers we can tap into `Combine` and have a shared source of truth.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class AppEventsManager {
    static let shared = AppEventsManager()
    var isFlipped : CurrentValueSubject<Bool, Never> = .init(true)
    
    private init() { }
}
```

Then you can subscribe to changes in the Views that need them.

```
//Observes changes
struct FirstView: View {
    @State private var isFlipped: Bool = false
    @State private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []
    
    var body: some View {
        Image(systemName: "person")
            .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: isFlipped ? 360: 0), axis: (x: 0, y: isFlipped ? 360 : 0, z: 0))
        
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2), value: isFlipped)
            .task {
                AppEventsManager.shared.isFlipped
                    .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                    .sink { isFlipped in
                        self.isFlipped = isFlipped
                    }
                    .store(in: &cancellables)
            }.onDisappear {
                self.cancellables = .init()
            }
    }
}
//Makes Changes
struct SecondView: View {
    let manager = AppEventsManager.shared
    var body: some View {
        Button("Toggle") {
            manager.isFlipped.send(!manager.isFlipped.value)
        }.buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        
    }
}
```